# Android:Fragment in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a strange problem I created a navigation drawer and a fragment.
when I insert a list view in the fragment it appears normally but if I remove that list view and insert anything else like text view or image view nothing appears in the fragment when I tap its item in the navigation drawer.

Note: I know that the list view need to be initialized in the java file too and I did that. is the text view or image view needs something like that? may be the error here... any help please....

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
    content.add("list");
    content.add("list");
    content.add("list");
    content.add("list");
    content.add("list");
    content.add("list");
    content.add("list");
    ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, content));
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment;
    switch(position){
        case 0: //search//todo
            break;
        case 1: //stats
            break;
        case 2: //my account //todo
            break;
        case 3: //settings //todo
            break;
        case 4: //location //todo
            fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LocationFragment.TAG);
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new LocationFragment();
            }
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, LocationFragment.TAG).commit();
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any error in logcat?

Comment: no errors and the list view itself sometimes disappears when I edit the code and I cannot restore it back

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"/>
</RelativeLayout> <<< that list view sometimes disappears >>>

Comment: I had something like this problem and changed getsupportfragmentmanager with getchildfragmentmanager , but i dont think this works for you! , share your code to check.

Comment: public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
        content.add("list");
        content.add("list");
        content.add("list");
        content.add("list");
        content.add("list");
        content.add("list");
        content.add("list");
        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, content));
    }